# can't download bin file for gzip file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I have a problem while trying to `session.dataTaskWithRequest` in a function to read gzip from URL.
The server side changes `.gzip` to `.bin` and stores the file.
I want to read the file with `.bin`. However, The network connection was lost.

However, a `The network connection was lost` error will occur.
Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Server side file name: `xxx.bin` (this bin file is a gzip file.)

Following the code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration 
defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://...../xxx.bin"];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL: url
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error [%@]", [error localizedDescription]);

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"success");

        }
    }];

[task resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try two steps of codes to download and extract zip files.   

 //Fetching zip file from server
    -(void)dataSyncFileDonload{
        NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yourzipfilecontainedURL"];
        stringURL =  [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [self extractDownloadedZipFile:urlData];
    }
    //File Extraction from Zip file
    -(void)extractDownloadedZipFile:(NSData *)data {

        //If you are using SQlite and storing in local directory for extraction
        NSData *outputData = [data gunzippedData];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *dataPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myAppDB.sql"];
        NSString *dataPath1 = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myAppDB.sql.gz"];
        dataPath = [dataPath stringByStandardizingPath];
        [outputData writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
        [data writeToFile:dataPath1 atomically:YES];
        [self readExtractedFile:dataPath];
    }

    //Read upzip file
    -(void)readExtractedFile:(NSString *)filepath loaderPercent:(float)loaderPercent loaderTo:(float)loaderTo{
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];//destinationPath
        NSString *fileString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSArray* allLinedStrings = [fileString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
        //You can use you data now.
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. At once I tried your suggestion. However, the size of urlData::length was 0.
Server side file name: xxx.bin (this bin file is a gzip file.)
Do you know how to deal with this problem?